# AngularJS - Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, closures, inline

For an experiment I wanted to inline my Javascript files and I've come across some unexpected behavior.

Everything works fine with a normal Angular import like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/js/angular.js"></script> <!-- Works fine! -->
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('example', []);
    </script>
    ...
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

However, It raises an exception if I inline the Angular source code like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>// Minified Angular source code </script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('example', []);
    </script>
    ...
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

The exception:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

Comment: Are you sure all the code is inlined?  Take a look at the position (line number, column number) of where `a` is not defined.

Comment: Positive. AngularJS is calling a from inside it's own scope.

Comment: you should try this with the non-minified version.  If it fails, it will be more a more descriptive error. If it doesn't fail, then maybe it is a copy-paste issue or something else.

Comment: Can you post this minified version to plunker?

Answer (score 1):

Happens to me with yeoman + grunt. Make sure you have your controllers setup like this before minification:

```
angular.module('project').controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function ($scope) { }
]);
```

And **not** like this:

```
angular.module('project').controller('MainCtrl',
    function ($scope) { }
);
```

If i remember correctly, its a "bug" of sorts with the way angular injects dependencies

Comment: Since angular 1.3 you can enable [strict DI mode](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/4b1695ec61aac8de7fcac1dfe8b4b420f9842c38) when bootstraping the angular app to prevent this.